# Changing Text Field default value based on a drop down list value

Tags: javascript, pdf-form

I am trying to change the title of a form field based on what category the user selects on a drop down list. Therefore, I want the value of the drop down list to change the default value of the Text Field. The code I am running is:

```
    var e = document.getElementById("Category");
    var selection = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    if(selection=="Main Event")
           {this.getfield("FormatType").defaultValue = "Main Event";}
    else   {this.getfield("FormatType").defaultValue = "Small Activity";}
```

I am working on a pdf form. However, when I finish editing and try to make it work, nothing happens.

Comment: Please also add the relevant JavaScript and HTML. What is `getfield`, where is the code that you've shown included in your overall script and when is it called?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and a how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all the relevant code so that we can see what might be causing the problem and be able to help.

Comment: Have you tried `value` instead of `defaultValue`? According to the docs https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acro6JS1.pdf, `defaultValue` is the default value plus the value that is used if the form is reset.